# WCF WSDL does not show any Operation/Method

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I have a simple WCF Service which currently runs locally:

```
http://localhost:63951/WcfService.svc
```

This shows the default site. The problem appears when I append ?wsdl to the URL:

```
http://localhost:63951/WcfService.svc?wsdl
```

[image: Wcf wsdl not showing any method/operation]

Unlike what I expected, this WDSL document does not show any operations/methods!

**IWcfService:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Ant.Domain.Model.DTO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Ant.Application.Service
{
    public interface IApplicationService
    {
        FileDTO GetFile(FileDTO fileDTO);
    }
}
```

**WcfService:**

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using Ant.Application.Service;
using Ant.Domain.Model.DTO;
using Ant.WcfService.Utils;


namespace Ant.WcfService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class WcfService : ServiceWExceptionManager 
    {
        ApplicationService ApplicationSevice = new ApplicationService();

        [OperationContract]
        public FileDTO GetFile(FileDTO fileDTO)
        {
            return this.Process(() =>
            {
                return this.ApplicationSevice.GetFile(fileDTO);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Ant.WcfService.WcfService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Ant.WcfService.WcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Ant.WcfService.WcfService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Ant.WcfService.WcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

What could cause a WCF .svc service not to show any operations in the WSDL Document?

Probably it is a stupid question but, using Google, I can't find an answer.
Also english is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: is this working fine when u try to consume the API.

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui I tried to make some requests using SoapUI, with no success

Comment: <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Snt.WcfService.WcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Snt.WcfService.WcfService" />

Comment: replace with the above code in web.config

Comment: [InvalidOperationException: The endpoint at 'http://localhost:63951/WcfService.svc' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.]

Comment: try this http://localhost:63951/WcfService.svc?SingleWsdl ,as I can see you're importing a WSDL file